# Music stops while scrolling in Cordova App

Tags: html, cordova, audio, phonegap

With the update to iOS 12.0.1, I noticed an issue with my app built in Cordova.

I have an MP3 file playing, but when I scroll the audio pauses and then resumes when I stop scrolling. [See this video](https://youtu.be/08EZQHR5KYk).

The code I am using for the audio player is standard HTML:

```
<audio
  id="compline_audio"
  src="https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/pf.opcompline/compline_mon_ot.mp3"
  controls
  controlsList="nodownload">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
</audio>
```

Comment: I'm hitting this too with my Cordova-based music app in iOS. It started happening as of iOS 12. The strange thing is, this doesn't happen if I just use Safari and browse to my web app. It only happens when the web app is packaged up with Cordova as an iOS app.

Comment: Ok, good to hear I'm not crazy. Any ideas on what may be causing it?

Comment: I pinged one of the Apple devs on Twitter about this, he told me to file a bug. Here's the Twitter thread: https://twitter.com/JudahGabriel/status/1071069776666132480. I've filed a bug with Apple at the following URL, though it might not be public: https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=46595343

I'll update this comment or post an answer when I find out more.

Comment: I also reported the bug here: https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=46420245

It does not look like these reports are public, so you may not be able to access it, but I wanted to update this thread.

Comment: Ha, yeah, I just got a notification from Apple that they've closed my bug report after determining it's a duplicate of 46420245. So, please, keep me informed what Apple has to say about this issue.

Comment: Well, it's good to know they actually read the bug reports and that they're not just lost in the black hole of Apple Support.

Comment: In the Twitter thread (https://twitter.com/JudahGabriel/status/1071069776666132480), an Apple dev said this was a bug accidentally introduced during the fix to https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=186856. They are looking into a fix.

Comment: Disregard the above comment. (I have deleted it.) I misread your last post. To my knowledge this is still an issue.

Comment: It appears this has been fixed in Webkit / Safari - yay! https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=192829 This was mentioned by Apple Dev Jer Noble https://twitter.com/jernoble/status/1102915733443543040

Comment: Good news: Today's release of iOS 12.2 fixes the problem. Woohoo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit March 29th, 2019***: I'm pleased to report that this is fixed in iOS 12.2. I just tested it and verified it is working again.

---

This is a bug in WebKit introduced in iOS 12. It was fixed by [this patch](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=192829), and [tracked in this changeset](https://trac.webkit.org/changeset/239640/webkit), submitted in January 2019. This fix isn't yet included in any public iOS versions. At the time of this writing, iOS 12.1.4 is the latest version of iOS, and the fix is not present in this version.

I expect to see an iOS release sometime in 2019 with this fix included. I'll update this post when an iOS is released with the fix.